# number of ways of representing a positive integer as sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $n$, I want to know the number $$s(n)=\#\{(a,b)|\,a,b\in\mathbb{N_+},\,n=a^2+b^2\}$$ of ways of representing $n$ as sum of two squares.

How can we represent it if the factorization of $n$ is known.

Comment: The counting of the ways is nicely treated in this [previous MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares) question.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Formula" section of [sequence A000161 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000161), an explicit formula was mentioned by Ant King:

> Let $f(n)=$ the number of divisors of $n$ that are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ minus the number of its divisors that are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, and define $\delta(n)$ to be $1$ if $n$ is a perfect square and $0$ otherwise. Then $a(n)=\frac12 (f(n)+\delta(n)+\delta(\frac12 n))$.

This is a result from the paper [Some formulae for partitions into squares](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X99001594?via%3Dihub) by M. D. Hirschhorn, which contains its proof.

Comment: This formula differs in two respects from the count which appears in the Question.  As M.D. Hirschhorn defines his "partition" problem, zero summands are allowed and the order of summands is irrelevant.  The OP excludes zero summands and considers the order of the summands relevant.